# html form element detecting which html submit button is pressed?

Tags: html

I have 2 buttons in a html form. It is needed having 2 buttons on page to support customer requirements. I want to figure out which button is pressed on the backend.

Here is a simple code snippet;

```
<form method="get">
<button type="submit">Op 1</button>
<button type="submit">Op 2</button>
</form>
```

Submit buttons usage is only submitting the form. I want to figure out which submit button is pressed.

Comment: What's your backend language?

Comment: You'll probably have to add event listeners to both and then add that as `<input tyoe=hidden />` input your form before submitting it again to do this and pass it to your webserver. I don't think HTML has any way for this to be detected, really. I also think you shouldn't havce two buttons because of accessibility, but okay.

Comment: if you add the `name` attribute to the submit buttons, they will be a POST/GET parameter in the form request named as that and that you can retrieve server side

Comment: I was thinking if I do not mention the backend language, I can reach wide range of the users :) but it is .Net

Comment: @DiegoD Question: wouldn't it actually submit both buttons' values regardless of which button would be clicked?

Comment: you can also set the `value` attribute to set a specific value for the corresponding param passed to the form request. Server side you should just check if the param is present despite its value.. and the logic should be that the param passed will be only the one corresponding to the button pressed. I can't say anything specific about .NET because I don't know .. but that's how html forms are expected to work under the hood. In the old fashioned ASP.NET page life cycle, you had code behind mapped to controls

Answer (score 2):

Give the form elements a `name` and `value`:

```html
<form method="get">
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="op1">Op 1</button>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="op2">Op 2</button>
</form>
```

The code handling this form can just look for the `submit` value (or whatever you decide to name it) and see which value was provided.

(In your browser's debugging tools, observe the request being made when clicking either of the buttons in the snippet above.  The value of the clicked button is included in the request.)

Comment: Thanks, setting the name attribute sends its value to the backend. This solution fixed my problem.